# Tensorflow: How to use tf.keras.metrics in multiclass classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use some of these metrics when training my neural network:

```
METRICS = [
  keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
  keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
  keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
  keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
  keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
  keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
  keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='acc'),
  keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]

BATCH_SIZE = 1024
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 4000
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sent_vectors, labels))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embed_dim)))
for units in [256, 256]:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=METRICS)
model.fit(
    train_dataset, 
    epochs=100)
```

But I get `Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 1) are incompatible`. I believe this is because I am doing multiclass classification on 4 classes but the metrics are calculated based on binary classification. How do I adjust my code for multiclass classification?

**Update:** I am interested in gathering the metrics **during the learning process** like in [Tensorflow Imbalanced Classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#class_weights), not just at the end of the fitting process.

**Additional infos:**
My input data are numpy arrays with the shape `sent_vectors.shape = (number_examples, 65, 300)` and `labels=(number_examples, 1)`. I have 4 labels: 0-3.

Stacktrace:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-2b73afaf7726> in <module>
      1 model.fit(
      2     train_dataset,
----> 3     epochs=10)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    501       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    504     finally:
    505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     71     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
     72     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 73         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
     74     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     75     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    758       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    759                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 760       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    761 
    762   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1785       kwargs = {}
   1786     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1787       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1788 
   1789   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2130         self._container_strategy(),
   2131         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2132       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2133 
   2134   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    262       y,
    263       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 264       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    265 
    266   if reset_metrics:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    313     outs = [outs]
    314   metrics_results = _eager_metrics_fn(
--> 315       model, outs, targets, sample_weights=sample_weights, masks=masks)
    316   total_loss = nest.flatten(total_loss)
    317   return {'total_loss': total_loss,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _eager_metrics_fn(model, outputs, targets, sample_weights, masks)
     72         masks=masks,
     73         return_weighted_and_unweighted_metrics=True,
---> 74         skip_target_masks=model._prepare_skip_target_masks())
     75 
     76   # Add metric results from the `add_metric` metrics.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _handle_metrics(self, outputs, targets, skip_target_masks, sample_weights, masks, return_weighted_metrics, return_weighted_and_unweighted_metrics)
   2061           metric_results.extend(
   2062               self._handle_per_output_metrics(self._per_output_metrics[i],
-> 2063                                               target, output, output_mask))
   2064         if return_weighted_and_unweighted_metrics or return_weighted_metrics:
   2065           metric_results.extend(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _handle_per_output_metrics(self, metrics_dict, y_true, y_pred, mask, weights)
   2012       with K.name_scope(metric_name):
   2013         metric_result = training_utils.call_metric_function(
-> 2014             metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights=weights, mask=mask)
   2015         metric_results.append(metric_result)
   2016     return metric_results

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in call_metric_function(metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
   1065 
   1066   if y_pred is not None:
-> 1067     return metric_fn(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights)
   1068   # `Mean` metric only takes a single value.
   1069   return metric_fn(y_true, sample_weight=weights)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/metrics.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    191     from tensorflow.python.keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
    192     return distributed_training_utils.call_replica_local_fn(
--> 193         replica_local_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    194 
    195   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py in call_replica_local_fn(fn, *args, **kwargs)
   1133     with strategy.scope():
   1134       return strategy.extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
-> 1135   return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   1136 
   1137 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/metrics.py in replica_local_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    174     def replica_local_fn(*args, **kwargs):
    175       """Updates the state of the metric in a replica-local context."""
--> 176       update_op = self.update_state(*args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    177       with ops.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    178         result_t = self.result()  # pylint: disable=not-callable

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py in decorated(metric_obj, *args, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     with tf_utils.graph_context_for_symbolic_tensors(*args, **kwargs):
---> 75       update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     76     if update_op is not None:  # update_op will be None in eager execution.
     77       metric_obj.add_update(update_op)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/metrics.py in update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    881         y_pred,
    882         thresholds=self.thresholds,
--> 883         sample_weight=sample_weight)
    884 
    885   def result(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py in update_confusion_matrix_variables(variables_to_update, y_true, y_pred, thresholds, top_k, class_id, sample_weight)
    276    y_true], _ = ragged_assert_compatible_and_get_flat_values([y_pred, y_true],
    277                                                              sample_weight)
--> 278   y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    279 
    280   if not any(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)
   1113     """
   1114     if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
-> 1115       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
   1116 
   1117   def most_specific_compatible_shape(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Comment: Line `model.fit` causes the error. @learningthemachine I have edited the post to include the stacktrace.

Comment: Please, update your question your error to be reproducable with all relevant code part and with data sample

Comment: @sandboxj See my answer with working example

Comment: @Geeocode your answer only works post training or? Not during training like in the sample link provided in the question?

Comment: @sandboxj your original question was quite different, so you should update your question with transparent **EDIT:** and **UPDATE:** tags as the current situation misleading for future readers and against the SO policy.

Comment: @sandboxj which version of Tensorflow and Keras do you use?

Comment: tf 2.0.0 and tf.keras 2.2.4-tf

Comment: What do you consider a "true positive" and a "false positive" in a 4 class categorical problem? (With a proper answer to this, it's easy to create custom metrics).

Comment: The same goes for precision, recall and AUC

Comment: See my working example for metric type solution.

Comment: Thank you for accepting, but If you interested in I would have a more sophisticated answer and I would do an edit. Please confirm if you want it, don't to refer me with @Geeocode me to get a notification.

Comment: See my edited answer below with clearer functionality and result display. Categorical true positives are now integer number!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Update:

As OP edited his question, I decided to edit my solution either with the intention of providing a more compact answer:

**Import and define all we need later:**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as random
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras.backend as K

tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(False)

VERBOSE = 1

keras.backend.clear_session()
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.as_default()


### Just for dummy data
sent_vectors = random.rand(100, 65, 300).astype(np.float32)
labels = random.randint(0, 4, (100, 1))
labels = np.squeeze(labels, 1)

NUM_CLASSES = np.max(labels) + 1
BATCH_SIZE = 10
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 200
embed_dim = 8
### Just for dummy data
```

**Create custom metric:**

```
class CategoricalTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, num_classes, batch_size,
                 name="categorical_true_positives", **kwargs):
        super(CategoricalTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes    

        self.cat_true_positives = self.add_weight(name="ctp", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):     

        y_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
        y_pred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        y_true = K.flatten(y_true)

        true_poss = K.sum(K.cast((K.equal(y_true, y_pred)), dtype=tf.float32))

        self.cat_true_positives.assign_add(true_poss)

    def result(self):

        return self.cat_true_positives
```

**First compile and fit your model using only the metrics for multilabel evaluation including our custom function:**

> **Important note:** 
> OP provided a `label` shape `(number_examples, 1)`. Originally he used `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, but the built_in metric `keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy`, he wanted to use, is not compatible with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, instead I used `categorical_crossentropy` i.e. the **one-hot** version of the original loss, which is appropriate for `keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy`. Thus I one-hot encoded `labels` for the loss function.

```
METRICS = [
  tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='acc'),
  CategoricalTruePositives(NUM_CLASSES, BATCH_SIZE),
]

# Transform labels to onehot encoding for metric CategoricalAccuracy
labels = tf.compat.v1.one_hot(labels, depth=NUM_CLASSES)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sent_vectors, labels))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embed_dim)))

for units in [256, 256]:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=[METRICS])
model.fit(
    train_dataset, 
    epochs=10,
    verbose=VERBOSE,
    shuffle=True)
```

**Predict and postprocess the results:**

```
result = model.predict(train_dataset)

pred_size = sent_vectors.shape[0]

preds = K.argmax(result, axis=-1)
preds = K.one_hot(preds, NUM_CLASSES)

print("\nTrue positives per classes:")
for i in range(4):
    m = tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp')    
    m.update_state(labels[:, i], preds[:, i])
    print("Class {} true positives: {}".format(i, m.result()))
```

**Out:**

```
Epoch 1/10
10/10 [==============================] - 3s 328ms/step - loss: 1.4226 - acc: 0.2300 - categorical_true_positives: 23.0000
Epoch 2/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 1.3876 - acc: 0.2900 - categorical_true_positives: 29.0000
Epoch 3/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 1.3721 - acc: 0.2800 - categorical_true_positives: 28.0000
Epoch 4/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 1.3628 - acc: 0.2900 - categorical_true_positives: 29.0000
Epoch 5/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.3447 - acc: 0.3800 - categorical_true_positives: 38.0000
Epoch 6/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.3187 - acc: 0.3800 - categorical_true_positives: 38.0000
Epoch 7/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.2653 - acc: 0.4300 - categorical_true_positives: 43.0000
Epoch 8/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 1.1760 - acc: 0.6000 - categorical_true_positives: 60.0000
Epoch 9/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.1809 - acc: 0.4600 - categorical_true_positives: 46.0000
Epoch 10/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.2739 - acc: 0.3800 - categorical_true_positives: 38.0000

True positives per classes:
Class 0 true positives: 16.0
Class 1 true positives: 0.0
Class 2 true positives: 5.0
Class 3 true positives: 7.0
```

**Note:**

We can recognize, that the true positives' sum is not equal with our training result, that is because we trained and predicted our model against a different data get from `train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)`.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce these steps. `tf.keras.backend.max(result, axis=-1)` returns a tensor with shape `(:,)` rather than `(:,1)` which I guess is no problem per se. But it seems like `m.update_state` expects something different, because I get `InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'predictions must be <= 1'
b'Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (shape=(36,) dtype=float32) = '
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
b'y (shape=() dtype=float32) = '
1.0`. What shape does the `labels` variable have to be? Also, are the fp averaged?

Comment: @sandboxj I didn't tested the method, I will check it twice, but first of all I made a mistake max have to be argmax(). I update my answer. Furthermore to be able to do a test I need some sample data.

Comment: @sandboxj False positives are not averaged, because it makes no sense. Fps returns the number of False positives.

Comment: As far as I see it, what goes into `preds`and `labels` at the moment are numpy array in the form of for example `(36,)`. `(36,)` which contain floats which are either (`0., 1., 2. or 3.)`, e.g. `[1.,0.,0.,3.,...]`. The error I posted in my first comment occurs in this case, not sure what input `m.update_state(preds, labels)` expects?

Comment: @sandboxj I think `m` expexts as you described, what you have.

Comment: From the docs of `tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives` I believe the metrics doesn't work for multiple classes, but only takes in values between 0 and 1, so two classes only.

Comment: he can also implement this using custom metrics https://keras.io/metrics/

Comment: @sandboxj Though I'll soon get back with answer to your last issue based on the SO policy you should provide some basic data sample your issue to be easily reproducible, as I wrote earlier.

Comment: @nickthefreak can you provide some details on how multiclass labels can be returned as the example only shows how to use a given keras backend function. I would guess the custom function would have to be in a certain format to be able to be passed into the `tf` `metrics=` parameter in `model.compile` (and `model.fit`)

Comment: Or just use tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy