# How do I create multiple custom AUC metrics, one for each of the outputs, in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, auc

In TensorFlow 2.0, there's the class [`tf.keras.metrics.AUC`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC). It can easily be added to the list of metrics of the `compile` method as follows.

```
# Example taken from the documentation
model.compile('sgd', loss='mse', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

However, in my case, the output of my neural network is an `NxM` tensor, where `N` is the batch size and `M` is the number of separate outputs. I would like to compute the AUC metric for each of these `M` outputs separately (across all `N` instances of the batch). So, there should be `M` AUC metrics, each of them is computed with `N` observations. I tried to create a custom metric, but I am facing some issues. The following is my first attempt.

```
def get_custom_auc(output):
    auc = tf.metrics.AUC()

    @tf.function
    def custom_auc(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = y_true[:, output]
        y_pred = y_pred[:, output]
        auc.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
        return auc.result()

    custom_auc.__name__ = "custom_auc_" + str(output)
    return custom_auc
```

The need to rename `custom_auc.__name__` is described in the following post: [Is it possible to have a metric that returns an array (or tensor) rather than a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59952527/3924118). However, this implementation raises an error.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (strided_slice_1:0) = ] [3.14020467 3.06779885 2.86414027...] [y (Cast_1/x:0) = ] [0]
>        [[{{node metrics/custom_auc_2/StatefulPartitionedCall/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_161/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_5149]

I have also tried to create the `AUC` object inside the `custom_auc`, but this is not possible because I am using `@tf.function`, so I will get the error `ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.`. Even if I remove the `@tf.function` (which I may need because I may use some if-else statements inside the implementation), I get another error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar33 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar33/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
>        [[node metrics/custom_auc_0/add/ReadVariableOp (defined at /train.py:173) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_5174]

Note that, currently, I am adding these AUC metrics, one for each of the `M` outputs, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952716/3924118). Furthermore, I cannot simply return the object `auc`, because apparently Keras expects the output of the custom metric to be a tensor and not an AUC object. So, if you do that, you get the following error.

> TypeError: To be compatible with tf.contrib.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of .custom_auc at 0x1862e6680>, found return value of type , which is not a Tensor.

I've also tried to implement a custom metric class as follows.

```
class CustomAUC(tf.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, num_outputs, name="custom_auc", **kwargs):
        super(CustomAUC, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        assert num_outputs >= 1
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.aucs = [tf.metrics.AUC() for _ in range(self.num_outputs)]

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        for output in range(self.num_outputs):
            y_true1 = y_true[:, output]
            y_pred1 = y_pred[:, output]
            self.aucs[output].update_state(y_true1, y_pred1)

    def result(self):
        return [auc.result() for auc in self.aucs]
```

However, I am currently getting the error

> ValueError: Shapes (200,) and () are incompatible

This error seems to be related to `reset_states`, so maybe I should also override this method. In fact, if I override `reset_states` with the following implementation

```
def reset_states(self):
    for auc in self.aucs:
        auc.reset_states()
```

I don't get this error anymore, but I get another error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (strided_slice_1:0) = ] [-1.38822043 1.24234951 -0.254447281...] [y (Cast_1/x:0) = ] [0]
>        [[{{node metrics/custom_auc/PartitionedFunctionCall/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_98/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_5248]

So, how do I implement this custom AUC metric, one for each of the `M` outputs of the network? Basically, I want to do something similar to the solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59952716/3924118), but with the AUC metric.

I have also opened the [related issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36319) on the TensorFlow's Github issue tracker.

Comment: You faced one of the hardest tensorflow-keras problem. Probably you won't be able to use a newly defined metric as a function due to the error messages that you've got. I suggest you to define a custom metric `class` as you can read it [one of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305514/tensorflow-how-to-use-tf-keras-metrics-in-multiclass-classification/59309717#59309717) to a similar question.

Comment: @Geeocode I will try to have a look at that answer, but, if you can provide an answer to my specific question and it solves my problem, I will upvote and accept it ;)

Comment: Understood. :) I guess this solution will be a bit time consuming, but if tomorrow you will be stuck with this still, I will be back and look at it then.

Comment: Let me know if you are still stuck with it.

Comment: @Geeocode I was just trying to implement it, but I am not sure how I should define the actual class, e.g., if I should inherit from `AUC` or from `Metric` (and define a list of `AUC` objects inside the class). I would really appreciate if you can provide a specific solution to my problem, as I am currently not sure how I should implement it, given that I've never had to implement a custom class for a metric. P.S. I would really appreciate a complete and simple example.

Comment: @Geeocode Ok, I've done that (even though I only quickly read that thread). I will edit my question to include my first attempt to develop a custom class metric. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you, you can read it thoroughly and if you will find it faulty you can revoke it calmly. I am studying your question, ok.

Comment: FYI In tf 2.1 there is multi_label version of AUC metrics, please confirm, if you don't want to use 2.1 or what is your intention, because they need separate solution.

Comment: @Geeocode I hadn't noticed this parameter. How does this parameter actually affect the solution to my problem? Anyway, if you can provide a solution for both versions, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem like yours. I have a model with 3 outputs and and i want to compute a custom metric (ConfusionMatricMetric) for the 3 outputs (that have different number of classes each). I used a solution in here https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/ - Going lower level. My problem now is that I can't train the model because of

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

then I used

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

and now the models train, *very slow* but it can be saved

P.S. I also used `tf.keras.metrics.KLDivergence()` instead of my custom metric and reproduced the same experiment with the same results as above - trained & saved (`tf.saved_model.save`)